# Си. Условные операторы в макроопределении препроцессора. Возможно ли?

Tags: c, препроцессор

Нужно исключить отладочные `printf()` из программы, применяя константу препроцессора.
Обрамлять каждый вызов `printf()`

```
#if DEBUG == 1
printf();
#endif
```

не хочется. Можно ли сделать что-то типа:

```
#define printf(x,y) (if DEBUG == 1 printf(x,y) endif)
```

`#if` внутри макроопределений запрещены. Есть ли альтернатива?

Comment: поместить этот код внутрь обычной функции

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно определять макрос по разному в зависимости от значения `DEBUG`:

```
#if DEBUG==1
    #define printf_d(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__);
#else
    #define printf_d(...)
#endif
```

Но лучше сделать это немного по другому, проверяя не *значение*, а *факт наличия* макроопределения:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// . . .
```

Такой подход позволяет включить режим отладки простым указанием имени проверяемого макроса в Make-файле или даже в параметрах команды сборки.

Answer (score 7):

Объявите разные версии макроса PRINT - для отладки и обычную

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define PRINT(x,y) print(x,y)
#else
#define PRINT(x,y) 
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот прям не знаю даже, какому из 2-х вариантов (@kff или @gbg) отдать предпочтение: в обоих что-то да не нравится,

вот такой нравится:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define PRINT(...) print(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define PRINT(...) 
#endif
```

его и использую, а вот вместо `_DEBUG` тут **лучше использовать любой другой флаг**, чтобы отладочную печать можно было включить, независимо от глобальной оптимизации.

На самом деле, я часто использую немного другую схему: у меня есть разные версии `PRINT`, с разными префиксами, чтобы можно было логику вывода на печать детализировать на разных уровнях:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_PRINT
    #define PRINT(...) print(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define PRINT(...) 
#endif

#ifdef ENABLE_VERB_PRINT
    #define VERB_PRINT(...) print(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define VERB_PRINT(...) 
#endif

...
```

А в коде - уже расставляем версии `PRINT'ов`, в зависимости от логики работы функций:

```
void myFunc(){
    VERB_PRINT("func: %s", __FUNCTION__);
    ...
    if( !... ){
        PRINT("error:%...", ...);
    }
    ...
}
```

Теперь, можно не меняя код, управлять детализацией логирования, добавляя соответствующие флаги для препроцессора.