# Удаление бесполезного кода компилятором

Tags: c++, оптимизация, компиляция

Рассмотрим простой код.

```
void f() {
}

// ...

f();
```

Ясно, что функция `f` не делает ничего (точнее, не делает никакой полезной работы), поэтому компилятор может её спокойно "выбросить" без изменения поведения программы. (Вариант обращения к памяти за вершиной стека чтобы "сцапать" оттуда адрес возврата не берём, ибо "грязный хак", да ещё может и не сработать.)

Усложним задачу:

```
void g(int x) {
}

int calc_x() {
    // Долго и упорно что-то вычисляем.
}

// ...

g(42);        // Ни на что не влияет.
g(calc_x());  // А вот тут непонятно...
```

Ясно, что `g(42)` можно выкинуть. Но выкинуть `g(calc_x())` в общем случае нельзя, поскольку у `calc_x` могут быть побочные эффекты.

Соответственно, вопрос: *при каких условиях компилятор будет иметь право выбрасывать вызовы функции `g`?*

P.S. Я понимаю, что компилятор может оставить даже вызов `f()`, если отключены все оптимизации. Вопрос следует понимать именно так, как написано - не выбросит, а *имеет право выбросить*.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

Comment: Тоже не пойму вопроса - полагаться на то выбросит оптимизация ваш метод или нет не имеет смысла. Так если есть основания, что компилятор выбросит метод - то зачем его вообще писать?

Comment: @KromStern Проблема в определении условий того, что компилятор получит право убрать код как бесполезный. Технологии - компилятор `C++`. В ответе хочу видеть перечисление условий, при которых код может быть убран. ;-)

Comment: @rikimaru2013 Пример. Есть отладочный код и релизный. Нужно чтобы отладочный что-то писал в логи, а релизный исчезал полностью или почти полностью. Но без макросов.

Comment: На самом деле мой вопрос навеян вот этим: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484709/194374. Там решения на макросах, вот мне и стало любопытно как это можно сделать без них.

Comment: @kff, писать в логи это side effect, компилятор не может это выкинуть.

Comment: Полагаться на оптимизатор бесполезно, особенно учитывая то, что вы хотите добавить в "убираемый" код сторонние эффекты (`printf`). Слегка противоречиво..

Comment: OK. Я всё понял. Вопрос я сформулировал неверно.

Comment: Компилятор имеет право выкинуть **любой** код, не приводящий к побочным эффектам. Для этого в стандарте есть даже специальное правило "as if": компилятор имеет право выкинуть или добавить любые промежуточные вычисления, только чтобы конечный результат (вывод на консоль или в файлы) остался тот же.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор может превратить вызов `g(calc_x());` в следующий [псевдо]код:

```
int x = ...;
calc_x код
x теперь чем-то проинициализирован.
Здесь мог бы быть код из g, но его там нет. Увы.
```

Т.е. компилятор заинлайнил обе функции, после чего он смотрит, что `x` нигде не используется и на этом этапе он может выкинуть код вообще.

Для примера, вот такой C++ код:

```
void g(int x) {
}

int calc_x() {
    int x = 0;
    while(x < 500)
    {
        ++x;
    }
    return x;
}


int main()
{
    g(42);       
    g(calc_x()); 
}
```

Превращается в вот такой ассемблер(и в студии, и в gcc):

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

---

Если попытаться вывести общую закономерность, то можно считать так: если компилятор может доказать, что код не имеет побочных эффектов, то он может его выкинуть. В противном случае он не имеет право его трогать. Простые вычисления, это код свободный от побочных эффектов, поэтому компилятор и выкидывает его, в примере выше. Но «может» не значит, что он его выкинет. Поэтому полагаться на это нельзя.

Comment: Я уже понял, что неправильно задал вопрос. На самом деле он должен был звучать так: "как сказать компилятору, что код не имеет побочных эффектов". Я это понял только после прочтения Вашего ответа.

Comment: @kff, все же не совсем так. Код `main()` и в самом деле такой. Однако в объектном файле присутствуют обе функции (см. вывод `nm`) с  их выхолощенным кодом (`rep ret` и `movl $500, %eax
 ret`)

Comment: @avp, линкер их удалит, скорее всего

Comment: Не, `nm` говорит, что обе остались.

Comment: @avp, значит плохой линкер в GCC, или каких-то флагов не хватает

Comment: @avp, попробуйте флаги из [этого](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215782/do-unused-functions-get-optimized-out) вопроса

Comment: `--gc-sections ` не понимает, а без нее вместе с остальными флагами все равно функции остались. Впрочем, это скорее правильное поведение, я же написал функции, значит имею право их вызывать независимо от потока управления через вызов main (например, через отладчик или аналогичную используемой им  технику).

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, в приведенном примере компилятор выкинуть `f()` не может. По очень простой причине - это видимый извне символ. Что он может делать - это не вызывать `f()` в данной transaltion unit. Иными словами, inline into noop.

Это превращает вызов `g(calc_x())` в calc_x(). Теперь все зависит от содержимого `calc_x()`. Компилятор оценивает наличие побочных эффектов по следующим критериям - вызов третьих, непрозрачных функций, вызов прозрачных функций с побочными эффектами, вызов стандартных функций с известными побочными эффектами, модификация любых объектов кроме автоматических. Если ничего из этого не происходит, то код считается не имеющим побочных эффектов, и может быть выброшен компилятором.

Comment: «Видимый символ» — это понятие уровня объектного модуля, но не целой программы. В стандарте такого понятия нет, так что это компиляторозависимое поведение.

Comment: @VladD, а причем тут целая программа? Компилятор производит объектный модуль и только. В стандарте есть понятие external linkage, можешь использовать его. Я уж не говорю о том, что оптимизация и стандарт вообще мало пересекаются (кроме того, что стандарт ее разрешает с нечеткой формулировкой) и ответ на любой вопрос об оптимизации - это ответ компиляторозависимый с толикой здравого смысла.

Comment: Ну, например при том, что понятия «видимый символ» в стандарте языка нету. А значит, ответ, ссылающийся на видимые символы, должен упоминать конкретный компилятор и конкретную целевую систему.

Comment: @VladD, hair splitting. Еще раз повторю - вопрос про оптимизацию автоматически выводит ответы за грань стандарта.

Comment: Не согласен. По сути границы оптимизации определяются стандартом (as-if rule), а то, что конкретный компилятор из-за своего внутреннего дизайна не может выполнить определённую оптимизацию — личная проблема этого компилятора. У других компиляторов вполне может таких проблем не оказаться. Согласны?

Comment: @VladD, теоретически - да. Практически компиляторы конвенционального дизайна выполнить данную оптимизацию не могут. Если только CLang c его байт-кодом вместо объектного файла... Но у меня особой надежды на это нет.

Comment: И MSVC с whole program optimization может, по идее.